# Disable 404 error logging

Tags: nginx

In my configuration, I'm using:

```
error_page  404  /switch;
```

When I browse to /testABC, I see this error in my log:

```
open() "/usr/local/nginx/html/www/testABC" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

How can I disable this error?  I'm currently using the 404 as part of the site functionality.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you don't want 404 errors to show in your nginx error logs, `log_not_found` is the directive you want to configure.

By default, `log_not_found` is set to "on" which will report file not found errors in your main error log. To turn these off, just do:

```
log_not_found off;
```

Source: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#log_not_found

Comment: Is there a directive that turns off logging for 200 only?

Comment: You mean the access logs? That's a completely different log as far as I know.