# Nginx: how to avoid logging of not found files

Tags: nginx

If would like to avoid logging of these usseless rows

> Note: these are useless because our server is not running wordpress. So I'd like to simply avoid these lines in log file because we are monitoring error log files sizes and it cause false positive

[error] 22328#22328: *2090 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 77.89.13.110, server: , request: "GET /wp-admin.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock:", host: ""

how can I exclude these kind of rows?

Comment: try this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300199/disable-404-error-logging

Comment: @RichardSmith: you're wrong. This is not a PHP error. Is still at nginx-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved adding two `location` inf my `nginx` config file, one for both of `wp-admin` and `wp-login` calls.

In these I simply disabled logging.

I cannot and do  not want to disable logging of `404`, because if user reach a `404` there I must understand what is wrong.